# Proof based on geometry triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The angle between the median CM and the hypotenuse AB of right triangle ABC is equal to 30°. Find the area of ABC if the altitude CH is equal
to 4.

I am extremely sorry I tried but didn't make any desired progress that would help in solving the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: In a right triangle, you have $AB=2CM$. (If you don't know this, try proving it!) Also, $\triangle{CHM}$ is a $30-60-90$ triangle.

Please work on the question on your own before viewing the solution.

> Since $CH=4$ and $\angle{CMH}=30^{\circ}$, we have $CM=2CH=8$. We also know that $CM=AM=BM$, so $AM=BM=8$. Thus, your answer is $$\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot AB\cdot CH=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot(8+8)\cdot 4=\boxed{32}$$

Comment: Yeah I got it, that's y came back to give the answer to the question but u also answered it, thanks anyways... I was just strolling in our garden for night walk, and the idea flashed through my mind...